# Random ports on localhost trying to connect to RDP 3389

Tags: firewall, rdp, remote-desktop-services

I am having an issue of what seems to be unauthorized access to a server and would like to direct you to the images below.

Event Viewer:
[image: Event Viewer]

Wireshark:
[image: Wireshark]

From the event log viewer I am seeing there is a login type of 10 (which research shows me is a remote login). Yet the source of the login is the local machine with a source IP of `127.0.0.1`.

Secondly my Wireshark capture is showing traffic from `localhost` to `localhost` with random usernames. Could I please be directed to where/how I could stop this and probably also find out how a remote login has a source IP of `localhost`.

Comment: Strong suggestion: Assume your server is virus infected, look for advice on how to clean it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)